# ToggleComment setting in NetBeans on C files

Tags: c, netbeans, ide, comments

Does anybody now, if (and possibly where) can one set behavior of ToggleComment action in NetBeans? I'm using NB 7.1 with C/C++ plugin and want to achieve, that a block of lines is commented as a couple of single line comments. Concretely
    `uncommented line 1
    uncomented line2`
I want it to comment (when pressed CTRL+slash) like
    `// commented line 1
    // commented line 2`
now I get
    `/*
      commented line 1
      commented line 2
    */`
but only in .c files, in .cpp or .java it works as I want.
Thank for hints in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using NB 7.2 at the moment you can change this here:

**`Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting -> Language: C -> Toggle Block Comment (Other)`**

if this is selected, NB will use a `/* ... */` block comment, else a single line `//`